# ASP.Net C# - MySQLTransaction multiple inserts

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, transactions

Following on from my previous question posted here ([Two insert queries with linked fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739695/two-insert-queries-with-linked-fields/24740224)), why does the following code insert 4 new rows in the 'question_m' table when I want to insert only 1 row?  Also, the following code inserts 16 new rows in the 'answers' table instead of 4 rows?

Here are screencaps of the tables after this code was executed:

'questions_m' table - https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3DrZ.png

'answers' table - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaTvO.png

```
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (MySqlTransaction tr = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            string queryUpdateQuestions = @"INSERT INTO questions_m (module_id, author_id, approved, question, type) VALUES (@module_id, @author_id, @approved, @question, @type);
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";

            using (MySqlCommand cmdUpdateQuestions = new MySqlCommand(queryUpdateQuestions, conn, tr))
            {
                cmdUpdateQuestions.Parameters.Add("@module_id", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmdUpdateQuestions.Parameters["@module_id"].Value = ddlModules.SelectedValue.ToString();
                cmdUpdateQuestions.Parameters.Add("@author_id", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmdUpdateQuestions.Parameters["@author_id"].Value = Session["UserID"].ToString();
                cmdUpdateQuestions.Parameters.Add("@approved", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmdUpdateQuestions.Parameters["@approved"].Value = 'N';
                cmdUpdateQuestions.Parameters.Add("@question", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmdUpdateQuestions.Parameters["@question"].Value = txtQuestion.Text;
                cmdUpdateQuestions.Parameters.Add("@type", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmdUpdateQuestions.Parameters["@type"].Value = ddlQuestionType.SelectedValue.ToString();

                int lastQuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(cmdUpdateQuestions.ExecuteScalar());
                ViewState["lastQuestionID"] = lastQuestionID;
            }

            string queryUpdateAnswers = @"INSERT INTO answers (question_id, answer, correct) VALUES (@question_id, @answer, @correct);
                                    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";

            using (MySqlCommand cmdUpdateAnswers = new MySqlCommand(queryUpdateAnswers, conn, tr))
            {
                cmdUpdateAnswers.Parameters.Add("@answer", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmdUpdateAnswers.Parameters.Add("@question_id", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                cmdUpdateAnswers.Parameters.Add("@correct", MySqlDbType.VarChar);

                int lastAnswerID = 0;
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(ddlNoOfAnswers.SelectedValue.ToString());

                for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++)
                {
                    cmdUpdateAnswers.Parameters["@answer"].Value = ((TextBox)this.FindControl("txtAnswer" + b)).Text;
                    cmdUpdateAnswers.Parameters["@question_id"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["lastQuestionID"]);
                    if (b == 1)
                    {
                        cmdUpdateAnswers.Parameters["@correct"].Value = "Y";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmdUpdateAnswers.Parameters["@correct"].Value = null;
                    }
                    lastAnswerID = Convert.ToInt32(cmdUpdateAnswers.ExecuteScalar());
                }
            }

            tr.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the value of `int a`?

Comment: @Rahul ddlNoOfAnswers.SelectedValue.ToString() so when I tested the code out, it was 4.

Comment: I don't see any reason why it should insert 4 rows for question_m table at least? Also, try using `ExecuteNonQuery` instead of `ExecuteScalar`

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar() is usually used to return/select some data from database. Use ExecuteNonQuery instead when you are executing any DDL queries.